# Storing Hindi language in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I know there are lot of answers for this question, but my need is something different. I am using Python(Flask) to work with Mysql (fetching, updating using Python Code). I don't want to this directly using Mysql like this

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `field_name` `field_name` VARCHAR(500) 
CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

In My Python I have like this

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
updatedsentence = "मेरा नाम Jay"
updatesentence = 'UPDATE table_name SET sentence=updatedsentence where uniquevalue="jh23"'
mycursor.execute(updatesentence)
```

Is there any way to convert that sentence in Python itself(with out using above MySQL query) before going to store in MySql?.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `charset` and `collation` parameters when you connect to the database. More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='joe', database='test', charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci')
```